# Can I ask about web template designing on Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have a template that is not nice, can I put an image of it on Stack Overflow or one of the Stack Exchange websites to find ideas, or have one of Stack Exchange's users give me an idea? For example, tell me to change that icon, put background for your DIVs, and so on.

Comment: Use chat for that. But there is a UX site and a (few?) design sites whose help center you might want to browse.

Comment: you *can* but you **shouldn't**... it would be a primarily opinion based, heavily downvoted and closed. Please see help-centre to see what is on topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Quite possibly on topic on Graphic Design, they have a [critique] tag - see this [+5 question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30824/critique-modified-template-for-a-greeting-card-service) and this [+2 question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30481/critique-can-you-provide-constructive-feedback-for-my-monochrome-website-design)

Comment: I know, I know, downvotes on Meta indicate disagreement. But please reserve that for [meta-tag:feature-request] and perhaps [meta-tag:discussion], don't downvote support questions.

Comment: Just in case you take my advice above: read [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) first.

Answer (score 5):

Not on Stack Overflow. 
What you are basically asking for is a review of your site. There is not (yet) a Stack Exchange site for reviewing websites, but there is a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68203/website-review) for such a site on Area 51.

For the code behind your website, you could go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but note that the site is for code, not for the design.
As @Mat observes in the comments, you *might* be able to use the [User Experience Stack Exchange site](http://ux.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their Help Center to see if your questions are on topic there!

There is also a [proposal for a Web Design site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647/web-designing) on Area 51, that you may be interested in.